# Jensen's inequality in measure theory

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convex-analysis

Here cites its original claim from [http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~ostrover/Teaching/18125.pdf](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/%7Eostrover/Teaching/18125.pdf).

> Theorem 3.1 Jensen's Inequality
>
> Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a probability space (a measure space with $\mu(X) = 1)$, $f: X \to \mathbb R \in L^1(X, \mu)$, and $\psi: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a convex function, then $$\psi\int_X f d\mu \le \int_X (\psi \circ f)d\mu$$.

Proof:

Since $\psi$ is convex, at each $x_0 \in \mathbb R$, there exist $a,b \in \mathbb R$ such that $\psi(x_0) = ax_0 + b$ and $\psi(x) \ge ax + b, \forall x \in \mathbb R$, (here, $y = ax + b$ defines a supporting plane of the epigraph of $\psi$ at $x_0$). Let $x_0 = \int_X fdµ$, then we have $$\psi(\int_Xf d\mu) = \psi(x_0) = ax_0+b=a\int_Xf\mu + b = \int(af+b)d\mu \le \int(\psi\circ f)d\mu$$, q. e. d.

Generally I have two questions. First is how could the $a, b$ be guaranteed to exist? The other is if the $\mu$ is not from probability space and just Lebesgue measure or even general measure, will this Jensen inequality still hold (I think the requirement is $\mu$ should be finite measure at least)?

Comment: 1) $\psi$ is convex and thus the epigraph also. 2)  you need to rescale the inequality. It makes no sense if $\mu$ is infinite.

Comment: @user251257: reply to 1. supporting hyperplane for convex set always exist and since this is $\mathbb R^2$, the hyperplane is just a line? 2. what did you mean by 'rescale'?

Comment: If $\mu$ is finite and non-zero, you could rescale it to a probability measure...

Comment: It's wired. This is an important inequality. But I haven't seen it proof in any ''analysis'' book. Does anyone know some ''analysis'' book mentions it and proves it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A counterexample with infinite measures. Let $m$ be the Lebesgue measure on $[1,\infty)$, $f(x)=x^{-1}$, and $\varphi(x)=x^2$. Then

$$\varphi\left(\int f\,dm\right)=\infty \quad\text{and}\quad \int \varphi\circ f\,dm=1.$$

Comment: Yes. I think infinite measure make no sense. How about all finite general measure? should it work?

Comment: Yes. In this case for convex $\varphi$

$$\varphi\left(\frac{1}{\mu(X)}\int fd\mu\right)\le \frac{1}{\mu(X)}\int \varphi\circ fd\mu$$

Comment: Seems to me that $f(x)$ is not integrable under Lebesgue measure on $[1,\infty)$, but $f(x)$ is assumed to be so in the statement of the theorem. I'm wondering for a $f$ integrable, is the finiteness of measure still needed?